# How can I create a temporary sequence column in my sql query result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like this.

```
NAME    AGE
james   22
ames    12
messi   32
....
....
```

I can query this table using `Select name, age from emp;`

Now what I want is having an extra column before name which will be 1,2,3..N if the query return n rows.

```
SEQUENCE    NAME    AGE
1    james  22
2    ames   12
3    messi  32
4    ....
    ....
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Do you want your result set ordered?

Comment: No there is no condition like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to just add a column which will contain sequence number at display time(not actually store that data in a table) you can use `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn or `row_number()` analytical function.

```
select row_number() over(order by name) seq
     , name
     , age
  from your_table

      SEQ NAME               AGE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 ames                12
         2 james               22
         3 messi               32
```

The output of the above query is ordered by `NAME` but you can order by any column or combination of columns you want.

Second approach is using `rownum` pseudocolumn. result is ordered by `name`  also

```
 select rownum seq
      , name
      , age
   from ( select name
               , age
           from your_table
          order by name
         )



       SEQ NAME               AGE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 ames                12
         2 james               22
         3 messi               32
```

Comment: The first solution has the advantage of being portable across a wide range of DBMS

Comment: I dint get your second approach . heximal wrote more simple query which use rownum

Comment: @Thinker Sub-query gives us ordered (by `name` column) set of data. And then, the outer query, uses `rownum` to number that ordered set of data. If you do not want ordered result set you can replace sub-query by your table name. But without ordering, rownum 1, for example, could be assign to a whatever row oracle has decided to select first.

Comment: I can't find row_number() function and mysql can't identify this function. What can I do in this situation .

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
Select ROWNUM sequence, name , age from emp;
```

For each row returned by a query, the ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows. The first row selected has a ROWNUM of 1, the second has 2, and so on.

Comment: I don't know more about Oracle. But it's really easy (simple) to get row number!

Comment: But be careful when using rownum for results that should be ordered or wher you have a condition on them.